# h:inputText rendering blank

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to implement some functionality shown on the [PrimeFaces website](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf). The p:commandButton in the header of my p:dataTable show a p:dialog containing a series of label/text outputs. The example below works as exepected :

DataTable:

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:dataTable id="table" 
                     value="#{locationStockList.getDataModel(cc.attrs.collection)}"     
                     var="item"
                     selection="#{locationStockList.selected}"
                     selectionMode="single">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{locationStockList.onRowSelect}"/>

            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <p:commandButton id="btnView" value="View"
                                 update=":form:panel" 
                                 oncomplete="dialog.show()"/>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Stock Item</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.stockItem.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Location</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.location.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.quantity}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.price}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Dialog

```
        <p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dialog" header="Location Stock Form" width="700"
                  resizable="false" draggable="false" closable="false" modal="true">
            <h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel id="lblStockItem" for="stockItem" value="Stock Item"/>
                <h:outputText id="stockItem" value="#{locationStockList.selected.stockItem.name}"/>
                <p:message id="msgStockItem" for="stockItem"/>

                <h:outputLabel id="lblLocation" for="location" value="Location"/>
                <h:outputText id="location" value="#{locationStockList.selected.location.name}"/>
                <p:message id="msgLocation" for="location"/>

                <h:outputLabel id="lblPrice" for="price" value="Price"/>
                <h:outputText id="price" value="#{locationStockList.selected.price}"/>
                <p:message id="msgPrice" for="price"/>

                <h:outputLabel id="lblQuantity" for="quantity" value="Quantity"/>
                <h:outputText id="quantity" value="#{locationStockList.selected.quantity}"/>
                <p:message id="msgQuantity" for="quantity"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Save" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" oncomplete="dialog.hide()" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when I try to implement the same dialog box as an edit/update panel. And change h:outputText in the p:dialog to h:inputText the textboxes are rendered empty. The only solution I have found to this problem is to set the h:inputText to disabled="true" or readonly="true", in which the values are visible but uneditable. To be specific:

These both show the values but do not permit modificaion :

```
<h:outputText id="price" value="#{locationStockList.selected.price}"/>
<h:inputText id="price" value="#{locationStockList.selected.price}" readonly="true"/>
```

While this renders empty:

```
<h:inputText id="price" value="#{locationStockList.selected.price}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both the table and the dialog are inside the **same** form, you're actually submitting the dialog's content as well when clicking the button in the table. What you're seeing are actually the submitted values of the dialog. When `readonly` or `disabled` is set, the input values won't be submitted and thus won't override the model values.

You need *either* to be more specific in what the button should process (i.e. only `@this`)

```
<p:commandButton value="View" process="@this" update=":form:dialog" oncomplete="dialog.show()"/>
```

*or* to split the table and the dialog over 2 forms

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable>
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:dialog>
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```